# Focused element jquery change css

Tags: jquery, css, focus

I am looking for a way to change css of the focused element.

```
input.on("select2-focus", function(elem) {
    console.log('FOCUSING');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```

What I am trying to do is, the clicked focus element should have the background color yellow.

But this is not working, it does not do anything.

Comment: Have you tried input.on('click', function() {...})?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Select2 will hide the original input and create a new component on your page. Your code targets the original input, which is hidden and styling it won't make any difference.

But you can get the select2 container from the input, like this:

```
input.on("select2-focus", function(elem) {
    var $container = $(this).data('select2').$container;
    $container.css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```

Comment: `var $container = $(this).data('select2').$container;`  should be .container right?

Comment: No. If you `console.log($(this).data('select2'))` you'll see that Select2 uses `$` as a prefix to its elements.

Answer (score 0):

Once check with this code

```
$(document).on("focus", ".select2-focus", function() {
    console.log('FOCUSING');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```